# Error with OnSolutionCallback using ortools

Tags: python, macos-mojave, or-tools, anaconda3

I tried adapting the code from here https://developers.google.com/optimization/scheduling/employee_scheduling, however I am getting this error when running:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type
> Swig::DirectorMethodException: SWIG director method error. Error
> detected when calling 'SolutionCallback.OnSolutionCallback

The code for my partial solution printer is:

```
class NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback):
    """Print intermediate solutions."""

    # def __init__(self, shifts, num_nurses, num_days, num_shifts, sols):
        # cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        # self._shifts = shifts
        # self._num_nurses = num_nurses
        # self._num_days = num_days
        # self._num_shifts = num_shifts
        # self._solutions = set(sols)
        # self._solution_count = 0

    def __init__(self, shifts, all_nurses, days, shifts_per_day, sols):
        cp_model.CpSolverSolutionCallback.__init__(self)
        self._shifts = shifts
        self._all_nurses = all_nurses
        self._days = days
        self._shifts_per_day = shifts_per_day
        self._solutions = set(sols)
        self._solution_count = 0

    def OnSolutionCallback(self):
        if self._solution_count in self._solutions:
            print('Solution %i' % self._solution_count)
            # for d in range(self._num_days):
            for d in self._days.keys():
                print('Day %s' % d)
                # for n in range(self._num_nurses):
                for n in self._all_nurses:
                    is_working = False
                    # for s in range(self._num_shifts):
                    current_shifts = list(self._shifts_per_day[str(days[d])].keys())
                    for s in current_shifts:
                        if self.Value(self._shifts[(n, d, s)]):
                            is_working = True
                            print('  Nurse %i works shift %i' % (n, s))
                    if not is_working:
                        print('  Nurse {} does not work'.format(n))
            print()
        self._solution_count += 1

    def solution_count(self):
        return self._solution_count
```

I am calling it like this in main:

```
    # Display the first five solutions.
    a_few_solutions = range(5)
    solution_printer = NursesPartialSolutionPrinter(shifts, all_nurses, days, shifts_per_day, a_few_solutions)
    solver.SearchForAllSolutions(model, solution_printer)
```

If someone could please help, that'd be amazing, it's kind of an emergency :(

Answer (score 2):

I recommend adding a try+except to your `OnSolutionCallback` to debug this kind of errors:

```py
import traceback

...
def OnSolutionCallback(self):
    try:
        if self._solution_count in self._solutions:
            print('Solution %i' % self._solution_count)
        ...
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        raise e
```

this gives me:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File ..., line 31, in OnSolutionCallback
    for d in self._days.keys():
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'keys'
```